How do I get comment notifications for a YouTube channel that is not mine?
I would like to get comment notifications for a YouTube channel that does not belong to me. Is this possible and, if so, how?
For context, I make instructional videos for my employer who posts the videos on their channel. I want to know when viewers post comments to ask questions.
